# Using a Stored Procedure parameter within the From of another

Tags: stored-procedures

I have a Stored Procedure that outputs totals from an eForm table.  I want to use this Stored Procedure to pull out data from other eForm tables and so want to replace the eForm table name in the From clause with a parameter.  I've read the other questions, but can't find one that helps with using a parameter in From.  The code for this Stored Procedure looks like this -

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('sp_SelectEformMonthlyTotals') IS NOT NULL
DROP PROCEDURE sp_SelectEformMonthlyTotals

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_SelectEformMonthlyTotals @EFORMNAME VARCHAR (200) = ''
AS
CREATE TABLE    #TEMP (EFORMNAME VARCHAR (200))
INSERT INTO #TEMP

EXEC sp_UpdateEForm @EFORMNAME

SELECT ....

FROM @EFORMNAME T1 INNER JOIN FLODS_CASE_ENQUIRY_F00 T2 ON T1.EFORM_CASE_ENQUIRY_ID = T2.CASE_ENQUIRY_ID

WHERE    T2.CREATED_DT >= '2012-04-02'
GROUP BY MONTH(T2.CREATED_DT), YEAR(T2.CREATED_DT)) T3
ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH_NUMBER

DROP TABLE #TEMP
```

This is the latest attempt of many and now includes a second Stored Procedure called sp_UpdateEForm -

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('sp_UpdateEForm') IS NOT NULL
DROP PROCEDURE  sp_UpdateEForm

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_UpdateEForm @EFORMNAME VARCHAR (200) = ''
AS
UPDATE FRANCIS
SET eFormName = @EFORMNAME
```

I created the Francis table to hold the eFormName.  I can see that I need to set the value of @EFORMNAME before sp_SelectEformMonthlyTotals can complete, but I just can't seem to find a way of doing this.

Thanks.

Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to use a dynamic query for this;

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_SelectEformMonthlyTotals @EFORMNAME VARCHAR (200) = ''
AS
CREATE TABLE    #TEMP (EFORMNAME VARCHAR (200))
INSERT INTO #TEMP

EXEC sp_UpdateEForm @EFORMNAME

DECLARE @sSQL AS VARCHAR(2000), @DateCreated as varchar(10)
SET @DateCreated = '2012-04-02'

SET @sSQL = 'SELECT .... '
SET @sSQL = @sSQL + ' FROM ' + @EFORMNAME + ' T1 INNER JOIN FLODS_CASE_ENQUIRY_F00 T2 ON T1.EFORM_CASE_ENQUIRY_ID = T2.CASE_ENQUIRY_ID '

SET @sSQL = @sSQL + ' WHERE    T2.CREATED_DT >= '' + @DateCreated + '''
SET @sSQL = @sSQL + ' GROUP BY MONTH(T2.CREATED_DT), YEAR(T2.CREATED_DT)) T3'
SET @sSQL = @sSQL + ' ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH_NUMBER'

exec @sSQL

DROP TABLE #TEMP
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  It didn't like sSQL, so changed this to @sSQL and then didn't like the single quotes within the SQL, so I set Quoted_Identifier Off and changed the sinqle quotes to double quotes and the Stored Procedure was created.  Running it results in an error "The name ' SELECT etc, etc' is not a valid identifier."  Changing to EXEC (@sSQL) resulted in "Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed", so I've hit of a bit of a brick wall?

Comment: Yeps missed out the `@` sign, just edited the answer

Comment: Thanks for the updated, but still having problems - "The name ' SELECT etc, etc' is not a valid identifier."  I have access to the full list of tables and may adopt this approach instead.  Ultimately this is going to be used in Visual Studio, so I can incorporate it as a selectable list instead.  Just would have been a little tidier including everything in the Stored Procedure.  Thanks.